# I'm troubled with AWS CodeBuild. which IAM Role is needed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

thanks in advance.

I'm stuck with AWS CodeBuild Error issue.

they say below messages all the way.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paayU.png)

I put proper docker images to repository, and source code is ready on codecommit repository too.

could you tell which IAM Role is needed? well, you know, the auto-maded IAM role is not worked well(with the above error messages), thus, I tried a lot of IAM role patterns.

I edited my ecs repository access authorities properly too.

and now I tried below IAM role,,, but it failed as always...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keKtt.png)

what's going wrong?

Comment: Since it could be either permission or repository naming issue based on the error, can you double check the name of docker regulatory repository?

Answer (score 0):

Please see step #3 on this documentation page for using ECR with CodeBuild (the policy to use on the ECR repository).  Your CodeBuild IAM role is not used to pull the Docker image from ECR.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-ecr.html